# Satellite assemblies and FullTrust issues when .NET exe is on the network

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, code-access-security, satellite-assembly, full-trust

I'm executing my .NET app from a network share.

Since framework 3.5 SP1, and as explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/12/fulltrust-on-the-localintranet.aspx, the main exe and all the DLLs located in the same folder (**but not subfolders**) are granted with FullTrust security policy.

My problem is that I have subfolders for satellite assemblies with localized strings.

Namely, I have:

```
1) FOLDER\APP.EXE
2) FOLDER\A whole bunch of DLLs
3) FOLDER\LANGUAGE1\Satellite assemblies
4) FOLDER\LANGUAGE2\Satellite assemblies
```

1 and 2 are automatically granted with FullTrust.

**3 and 4 are not and my application is really slow because of that.**

Is there a way to grant 3 & 4 FullTrust security policy at runtime, since the application running has FullTrust?

If not, is there a clean way to have satellite assemblies merged into only one DLL?

Comment: You can still use caspol.exe: http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx

Comment: I could but I need a solution that wouldn't involve forcing the users to change their computer security policy.

Comment: there's no such thing as C#.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign all your assemblies with a key created yourself.  Then give full trust to anything signed with your key (but that uses caspol one time for each client).  Alternatively, get a key from a trusted source and sign with that (but that costs money).